# It is not clear which version of vue.js is being used

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, vue-cli-4

I installed **npm install -g @vue/cli**

After installation, I create a project **vue create hello-world**

After creating the project, I run the following command: **npm list vue** Returns `-- vue@3.2.20. This indicates that the project is using vue.js version 3.2.20

But if you look in package.json, then the version of "vue" will be indicated there: **"vue": "^3.0.0",**

It confuses me. How to fix it?. It is not clear to me which version is being used in the project. If I go to vue ui, then version 3.2.20 will also be indicated there. But the package.json of the project shows version 3.0.0. How to fix it? Explain what's going on?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caret (^) in your package.json indicates that Vue will be updated to all future minor versions without exceeding the major version (version 3 in your case).

The version you got through `npm list vue`, 3.2.20 matches this rule 3.X.X

For more info on carets(^) and tildes (~), check the following question:
[Difference between tilde and caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json).